# Receiving seemingly random IndexErrors when processing "large" csv-files

Tags: python, csv

I'm currently working on a script to process ~60-70 MB csv-files. First, I translate the csv-file from a tab-file (not necessary but whatever, not the issue here). In the next step, I go through the rows of the csv to do two things:
1) Check the value in column two. If this value has changed since the last row, create a new output file.
2) Transfer some column values of the current row to the output file.
I have several tab-files that the script goes through automatically. It works fine for most of them, but sometimes I get an...

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

... for no obvious reason. I had a look at the csv-file that it was splitting and the rows before and after the error look just the same.

I tried to work around by making a try/except for the outputWriter which worked for at least some errors (which is already suboptimal as I don't want to lose data). But then I get the same error from another line of code which also handles the index variable.

To give you an example, here are the last three lines in my output file before the script stops:

```
154881105,-0.293776585182967
154883302,0.168302231277491
154883397,0.175177022786097
```

Here are the corresponding lines it is reading from plus the one that should've been next:

```
87018,23,154881105,-0.293776585182967
87019,23,154883302,0.168302231277491  
87020,23,154883397,0.175177022786097
87021,23,154883513,0.949924732250711
```

Am I missing something? I don't see any reason why index should be out of range.

Finally, here is the part of my code that should be relevant:

```
        with open (newCsv, 'rU') as csvfile: 

        plotlist = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', dialect=csv.excel_tab)

        x = 0

        for i, row in enumerate(plotlist):

            if is_number(row[1]):

                if row[1] != x:
                    x = row[1]
                    fileName = "sample" + str(x) + ".csv"
                    outputFile = open(fileName, "w")
                    outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)
                    outputWriter.writerow(["y","x"])

                outputWriter.writerow([row[2], row[3]])
```

Anyone got any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: For debugging purpose before issuing the last `writerow` print the entire row and tell the output.

Comment: For example: `if len(row)<=3: print 'Here it is!'`

Answer (score 1):

Those lines only have 2 items: But you're using index[3]. Is out of range. (?)

Comment: Indeed, I followed the suggestion by Alireza and those lines apparently only have 2 or the next even just 1 item. But why?

Answer (score 1):

The error below explicitly tells you that for sure you are getting an index which is not actually present in the list:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So for better debugging you can trace step by step before error:

```
if len(row)<=3: 
    print "Here's the culprit: %s" % row
```

You would almost see what is the issue by the above code :)

Comment: Yup, I can see that the error-causing row carries only 1 or 2 items. Now I need to figure out why, because the line clearly consists of 4 elements separated by ","